# Sind darlegen und erklären austauschbar?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Ich möchte ***darlegen***, wie schnell dieses Auto fährt.

Kann man auch sagen:

> Ich möchte ***erklären***, wie schnell dieses Auto fährt.

Was ist der Unterschied dazwischen und warum? Danke!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.
The two words cannot be substituted for each other in general, but they can be on certain occasions.

"Erklären" describes the (maybe informal) act of actually explaining someone how something works. 
For example, "Ein Lehrer erklärt seinen Schülern, wie ein Motor funktioniert". In this sentence, "darlegen" would not be appropriate, since a teacher does not formally address his students. The same would be for friends.

"Darlegen" is a rather formal word, describing the act of showing (rather than explaining, since you expect the other person to understand what you are saying, without further need of explanation) the concrete nature of or opinion about a certain thing. 
For example, a lawyer or a scientist could use "darlegen" to show someone in a formal setting a certain strategy or idea in a point-by-point manner.
"Des Weiteren werde ich darlegen, warum ich glaube, dass mein Mandant unschuldig ist." or "Um ein Verständnis für dieses System zu entwickeln, werde ich die einzelnen Schritte im Folgenden darlegen."

tl;dr: As a rule of thumb, I would suggest that you can and should use "darlegen" instead of "erklären" if it happens to be a very formal setting (lawyers, letters to government institutions etc.) and if you are not addressing someone in particular (e.g. a scientific research paper). "Erklären" could carry here a certain tone of belittlement. 
On the other hand, "erklären" or "zeigen" should be used in normal conversation, since "darlegen" could be interpreted as overly pretentious.

EDIT: source: German native speaker

Comment: Das hier ist ein Forum, das die deutsche Sprache zum Inhalt hat. Der Fragesteller hat die deutsche Sprache benutzt, um in diesem Deutsch-Forum eine Frage über einen Aspekt der deutschen Sprache zu stellen. Deine eigene Muttersprache ist, laut deiner eigenen Angabe, ebenfalls Deutsch. Also warum schreibst du deine Antwort in einer Fremdsprache?

Comment: a) Weil die Sprache der Wissenschaft de facto Englisch ist und auch wenn die Frage an sich leicht zu verstehen war, meine Antwort eventuell für Nicht-Muttersprachler auf Deutsch etwas schwerer zu verstehen gewesen wäre, als auf Englisch. Es wäre vielleicht sinnvoll eine dieser Diskussion http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/304/16190 analoge Frage hinsichtlich der Antworten zu stellen...


b) Aus Reflex, weil hier manche Fragen auf Englisch und auf Deutsch gestellt werden, ich nicht aufgepasst hatte und am Ende dann keine Lust mehr hatte, auf dem Handy alles nochmal auf Deutsch zu tippen...

Comment: 1. Warum glaubst du, dass alle, die sich für Deutsch interessieren, besser Englisch als Deutsch sprechen? Was ist mit Italienern, Serben, Türken, Russen, usw.? 2. http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/303/what-language-should-be-preferred-for-questions/830#830

Comment: Ich habe nie gesagt, dass "alle" [...] besser Englisch als Deutsch sprechen. Nur, dass ich glaube, dass die meisten, die diese Webseite hier besuchen eher schlechter Deutsch als Englisch sprechen.
Aber wie gesagt: Grundsätzlich habe ich nichts dagegen auf Deutsch zu antworten, wenn die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt wurde, nur passiert es mir manchmal im Eifer des Gefechtes, dass ich ins Englische, meiner persönlichen Stackexchange-Defaultsprache, verfalle. Jeder sollte in jeder Sprache fragen und antworten dürfen, die ihm am besten gefällt. Sind doch keine Sprachisten hier.

Comment: Du sagtest: "ich glaube, dass die meisten, die diese Webseite hier besuchen eher schlechter Deutsch als Englisch sprechen." Ich glaube genau das Gegenteil. Insbesondere verkehren hier mit Sicherheit ausschließlich Menschen, die sich für Deutsch interessieren. Über die Englisch-Fähigkeiten dieser deutsch-affinen Menschen kann man nur spekulieren. Man kann daher ausschließen, dass sich hier Personen herumtreiben, die kein Deutsch verstehen, während es durchaus sein kann, hier jemanden zu treffen, der kein Englisch kann.

Answer (score 1):

"erklären" ist das normale Wort, "darlegen" eine gehobene Variante, die viel seltener gebraucht wird. In normaler Umgangssprache kaum gebraucht.